# Subset a dataframe using colnames from another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

**Question:**

I have a particular problem where I want to subset a given dataframe columnwise where the column names are stored in another dataframe.

**Example using mtcars dataset:**

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

col_names <- c("hp,disp", "disp,hp,mpg")
df_col_names <- as.data.frame(col_names)

vec <- df_col_names[1,] # first row contains "hp" and "disp"
mtcars_new <- mtcars[, c("hp", "disp")] ## assuming that vec gives colnames
```

I even tried inserting double quotes to each of the words using the following:

**Attempted solution:**

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

col_names <- c("hp,disp", "disp,hp,mpg")
df_col_names <- as.data.frame(col_names)

df_col_names$col_names <- gsub("(\\w+)", '"\\1"', df_col_names$col_names)
vec <- df_col_names[1,]
vec2 <- gsub("(\\w+)", '"\\1"', vec)

mtcars_new <- mtcars[,vec2] ## this should be same as mtcars[, c("hp", "disp")]
```

**Expected Solution**

`mtcars_new <- mtcars[,vec2]`  is equal to `mtcars_new <- mtcars[, c("hp", "disp")]`

Comment: Not clear what kind of output you want. Is it one data frame with columns `hp,disp` and another one with `disp,hp,mpg`? Please show how you want it to be.

Comment: Ok editing the question to make it more clear, its hp,disp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need this?

```
lapply(strsplit(as.character(df_col_names$col_names), ","), function(x) mtcars[x])

#[[1]]
#                     hp  disp
#Mazda RX4           110 160.0
#Mazda RX4 Wag       110 160.0
#Datsun 710           93 108.0
#Hornet 4 Drive      110 258.0
#Hornet Sportabout   175 360.0
#.....

#[[2]]
#                     disp  hp  mpg
#Mazda RX4           160.0 110 21.0
#Mazda RX4 Wag       160.0 110 21.0
#Datsun 710          108.0  93 22.8
#Hornet 4 Drive      258.0 110 21.4
#Hornet Sportabout   360.0 175 18.7
#....
```

Here, we split the column names on comma (",") and then subset it from the dataframe using `lapply`. This returns a list of dataframes with length of list which is same as number of rows in the data frame.

---

If you want to subset only the first row, you could do

```
mtcars[strsplit(as.character(df_col_names$col_names[1]), ",")[[1]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do this:

```
col_names <- c("hp,disp", "disp,hp,mpg")

vec2 <- unlist(str_split(col_names[[1]],','))
mtcars_new <- mtcars[,vec2]
```

What you are doing is picking the first element from the `col_names` vector, splitting it by the separator, then unlisting it (because str_split() makes a list), then you are using your new vector of names to subset the mtcars data-frame.

Comment: I accepted @Ronak answer but I upvoted yours. Thanks so much!