# How do I subset a dataframe using values from another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, subset

Let's say I have one dataframe that represents a subset brief. Let's call this dataframe `brief`. Here, the values are the subset rules.

```
library(tidyverse)

brief <- data.frame(apple = 1, orange = 2, pear = 3)
```

In a second dataframe, called `types`, this is the data I'd like to subset.

```
types <- data.frame(apple_cake = rnorm(5,0,1),
                    apple_pie = rnorm(5,0, 1),
                    apple_ice = rnorm(5,0, 1),
                    orange_cake = rnorm(5,0,1),
                    orange_pie = rnorm(5, 0, 1),
                    orange_ice = rnorm(5,0, 1),
                    pear_cake = rnorm(5,0,1),
                    pear_pie = rnorm(5, 0, 1),
                    pear_ice = rnorm(5,0, 1)
)
```

In my example, I'd like to subset specific apple, orange, and pear food items using dataframe one against dataframe two.  I'd like to use the values from the first dataframe `brief` to subset the columns from the second dataframe `types`.

I would like to end up with a final dataframe as follows:

```
final <- types %>% 
  select(apple_cake, orange_pie, pear_ice)
```

In the final solution, apple item 1, orange item 2, and pear item 3 remain.

I've tried various dplyr functions but to no avail. I have also looked for similar [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53279315/subset-a-dataframe-using-colnames-from-another-dataframe) but do not think they address my problem because these examples might have similar column names across two dataframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, we split the data columns into a `list` of data.frame having similar prefix by splitting on the suffix removed column names, Extract (`[`) the columns from the corresponding index in `brief` data with `Map` and `cbind` the columns in the `list` with `do.call`

```
do.call(cbind,  Map(`[`, split.default(types, trimws(names(types), 
       whitespace = "_.*")), brief))
```

-output

```
 apple_cake   orange_pie   pear_ice
1  0.9065347  0.661994002  0.1988529
2  1.0429968  0.736754956  0.9714787
3  0.5517950 -0.003860467  0.4486231
4 -0.4304989  1.160817987 -0.3410640
5 -0.1701651  0.489398131 -1.1846220
```

---

Or another option is to loop over the data.frame `brief` with `imap`, `select` the columns with a select-helper (`starts_with`) on the names of the `brief` data column (`.y`) and then `select` based on the value index of the `brief` column (`.x`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
imap_dfc(brief, ~ types %>%
     select(starts_with(.y)) %>% 
     select(all_of(.x)))
  apple_cake   orange_pie   pear_ice
1  0.9065347  0.661994002  0.1988529
2  1.0429968  0.736754956  0.9714787
3  0.5517950 -0.003860467  0.4486231
4 -0.4304989  1.160817987 -0.3410640
5 -0.1701651  0.489398131 -1.1846220
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I particularly like the tidyverse solution because I can see the steps clearly. Because I had created an object with a similar name as a tidyverse function, I have now edited my original post and have named the object `brief`.